# ml-engine - no module named trainer

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

I have a directory of:

```
/ml_engine
  setup.py
  /trainer
    __init__.py
    task.py
    model.py
```

I have a custom model used with sklearn mixins that allows me to use the model as a sklearn model.

However when I try to upload the model I would get the error:

```
gcloud alpha ml-engine versions create m_0_03 \
--model model_9281830085_204245556_prophet \
--origin gs://BUCKET/9281830085_204245556/2018-08-23T13:37:00.000218 \
--runtime-version=1.9 \
--framework SCIKIT_LEARN \
--python-version=3.5 \
--package-uris=["gs://BUCKET/model_packages/trainer/"] \
--model-class=trainer.model \

Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......
...................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Could not load the model: /tmp/model/0001/model.pkl. No module named 'trainer'. (Error code: 0)"
```

Does ml-engine with alpha commands support this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `python setup.py --sdist` and then upload `dist/trainer.tgz` to GCS and use that as `--package-uris`.

Comment: When I tried to do this, I got: `ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: User-provided package dist.tar.gz failed to install: Command '['python-default', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/tmp/custom_lib', '--no-cache-dir', '/tmp/custom_code/dist.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Error code: 0)"`

Comment: However, if I downloaded the same package, it would install correctly, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: can you reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com and reference this thread so that we can better serve you?

Answer (score 0):

I using sklearn_crfsuite estimator

```
crf = sklearn_crfsuite.CRF(

    algorithm='lbfgs',
    c1=0.1,
    c2=0.1,
    max_iterations=2,
    all_possible_transitions=True
)
```

I'm saving the model as described below:

```
model = 'model.joblib'

joblib.dump(crf, model)
```

and when I try to deploy the model it reports this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected
>   with error: "Failed to load model: Could not load the model:
>   /tmp/model/0001/model.joblib. No module named
>   sklearn_crfsuite.estimator. (Error code: 0)"

deploy model:
gcloud alpha ml-engine versions create v1 --model teste --origin $ORI --python-version 2.7 --runtime-version 1.8 --framework scikit-learn