# gcloud ml-engine local train ... No module named XXX

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I am having a similar issue as

[ml-engine - no module named trainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994295/ml-engine-no-module-named-trainer)

I have a trivial GoogleCloud ML project structure

```
/foo
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  /bar
    __init__.py
    baz.py
```

my setup.py is

```
"""Cloud ML Engine package configuration."""
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = []

setup(
  name='foo',
  version='1.0',
  install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
  packages=find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True,
  description='Foo'
)
```

but when I run

```
gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name=bar --package-path foo
```

I get

```
/Users/peter.wolf/.conda/envs/ie/bin/python: No module named bar
```

What am I missing?  Why is it doing this?

Many thanks
P

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I got it

```
gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name=foo.bar.baz --package-path foo
```